# request.format is null on XMLHttpRequest() to rails server

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that is responding to requests at the url '/copy/:collection/:email'. From the app, I'm sending the request with an `XMLHttpRequest()` as:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(req);
}
req.open("GET", '/copy/' + collection + "/" + copyTo, true);
req.send();
```

The server receives the request and performs the correct action, but on completion returns a `Completed 404 Not Acceptable in ...`

I notice in the log that where it might normally say `Processing by XController#copy as JS`, the log only reads: `Processing by XController#copy as`. I've put in some debug and determined that request.format is nil. Is there a way to set this when sending my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to add an extension to the URL like so

```
req.open("GET", '/copy/' + collection + "/" + copyTo + ".js", true);
```

Another way would be set the Accept header for the http request to text/javascript. I believe this would be done like so (not tried it myself)

```
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")
req.open("GET", '/copy/' + collection + "/" + copyTo, true);
```

Comment: Or even better, `req.open("GET", "/copy/#{collection}/#{copyTo}.js", true);`

Comment: Thanks, had a little proximity blindness there.